# Laravel eloquent many to many to many model

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm doing a project in laravel 4, and I have come to a stop.

tasks table:

```
task_id (PK)
task_title
```

measurements table:

```
measure_id (PK)
measure_title
```

routines table:

```
routine_id (PK)
date
time
value
emp_id (FK)
```

emps table:

```
emp_id (PK)
first_name
last_name
user_name
email
user_type
```

Now what I am confused about is how I would model these relationships in eloquent, because I can't seem to figure it out. In the `phpmyadmin` DB, I currently have two tables connecting the tasks and measurements to routines which have `task_routine` : `task_id (PK)`, `routine_id (PK)` and `measure_routine` : `measure_id (PK)`, `routine_id(PK)`.

Hope that was as clear as it sounded in my head when I wrote it, and thanks for your help!

Comment: What is your question exactly ? How you want to build your relationships between which tables ?

Comment: Yeah - are you looking just for the way to set this up, or for a way to connect tasks to measures directly?

Comment: check out this tutorial... http://vegibit.com/many-to-many-relationships-in-laravel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first in your all tables change the `PK` field from `*_id` to just `id`. If you want to make a relation for a table with another table then the convention is that, you should keep a foreign key in the child table using the parent table's `name_id` (name should be in singular form), for example, to build a relation between `emps` and `routines` table you should use `emp_id` foreign key in the `routines` table and your `emps` table should contain `id` `PK`. So, your `emps` table is parent table and the `routines` is the child of `emps` and in both tables records should be like this (custom convention could be used):

Table `emps` (parent):

```
id (pk) | first_name | more fields ...
    1   | Mr         | ...
    2   | Miss       | ...  
    3   | Mrs        | ...
```

Table `routines` (child):

```
id (pk) | emp_id (FK) | more fields ...
    1   |    1        | ...            - Child of emps table's first record
    2   |    3        | ...            - Child of emps table's third record
    3   |    3        | ...            - Child of emps table's third record
```

Here, each `id` of `emps` table used as foreign key in the `routines` table in `emp_id` field. So, `emps` table has three related records in `routines` table and the first record  in `emps` table relates to first record in the `routines` table and the third record in the `emps` table (with id `3`) has two related records in `routines` table (second and third) because both records contains id `3` of `emps` table's third record in `emp_id` field.

### Now building relation using Laravel:

If your parent table has only one related table in child table then use `one-to-one`, for example, if the record with id `1` (first record) in `emps` table has only one related record in `routines` table using `emp_id` field with value of `1` and if it can't be in more than one record in the `routines` table then it's `one-to-one` relation and in the example records given above is not `one-to-one` relationship because in the `routines` table there are two records with same `id/pk` of `emps` table available so it goes to `one-to-many` relationship, so it could be read as `emps` on record has many `routines`. To build the `one-to-many` relation we may use:

```
class Emp extends Eloquent {
    public function routines()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Routine');
    }
}
```

The `Routine` model:

```
class Routine extends Eloquent {
    public function emp()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Emp');
    }
}
```

In `one-to-many` relationship a parent table may contain multiple child records with same `id` but if a record in child table has many parents as well then it should be a `many-to-many` relationship. For example, if we want to build a relation in routines table something like this (Not possible to use same primary key twice):

```
id (pk) | emp_id (FK) | more fields ...
    1   |    1        | ...            
    2   |    2        | ...            - Record 2(id) has parent 2(emp_id)
    2   |    3        | ...            - Record 2(id) has also parent 3(emp_id)
```

In this case this is a `many-to-many` relationship and it's not possible to use same `id/PK` twice in one table so we need to build the `many-to-many` relationship between `emps` table and `routines` table using a third table (known as `pivot` table) to maintain the `many-to-many` relationship. So, it'll look something like following table:

Table Name should be `emp_routine` but there is other way to use a
different name but follow this convention.

### `emp_routine` Pivot Table:

```
id (pk) | emp_id (id/PK of emps) | routine_id (id/PK of routines) | more fields ...
    1   |   1                    |    1                           | ...
    2   |   2                    |    1                           | ...
    3   |   1                    |    2                           | ...
```

Here, both parent and child has more than one related records in both tables and this `pivot` table maintains the relationship.

To build the relationship using `Laravel` we may use:

```
class Emp extends Eloquent {
    public function routines()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Routine');
    }
}
```

The `Routine` model:

```
class Routine extends Eloquent {
    public function emp()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Emp');
    }
}
```

In this case, we don't need a foreign key field (emp_id) in the `routines` table because we are using a pivot table to maintain the relationship but if it's there, it won't be problem.

It should be notice that whenever you insert/update any record in the parent table you also have to insert/update relational data in the pivot table as well and Laravel provides helpful methods for these, so [check the manual (relationship)](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the long answer, it helped me a lot in understanding how it works.

How would this work if the emp table in your example had a many to many relationship with two tables ?

Just extend Eloquent for all three tables and run the belongsToMany function on the two tables towards emp, and then emp towards the two tables ?

Comment: Yes, for `many-to-many` relationship use `belongsToMany` from each models and use `pivot` table.